# Bioprocess data visualisation and analysis

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for some kind of software, ideally FOSS, that will allow us to plot, compare, annotate and add additional points to time series data from bioprocessing runs (bioreactors).
Many of the bioreactors come with some of their own quite limited software to do this, but it cannot be installed on other computers.

I have looked around a fair amount but can only expensive-looking biopharma software. Is there any academic software to achieve this?
I was considering that writing it myself wouldn't be that difficult with python, but I don't want to waste effort.

(maybe this SE is not the best for bioprocessing, not sure where else to ask.)

Comment: Welcome @Alext. Generally, the question isn't sufficiently specific about what is required, few of us will understand bioprocesser measurements, although alot will understand timeseries. In the public domain one approach is adapting IoT https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/11/24/11932, where IoT is connecting a device to a computer and accessing the output. GCP has strong IoT capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer the technique here is called "Internet of Things" (IoT), where a machine, or an "IoT" device reports to either the cloud or another computer. In bioinformatics this technology has not embraced at present outside the industrial sector.

Google Cloud Platform (GCP) does have an IoT platform where the devices can be registered and data is streamed to the cloud. However, doing this operation across a LAN (local area network) is automatic and can be directed via `cron` notably in automating and collecting the data and analysing it periodically. For a generic IoT stack consider https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/11/24/11932

Comment: Thanks for your response :), however I am not asking about receiving the data in real time in this instance, I am aware of some industrial standards like OPCUA that can be used for this, but rather some software to use after the run, to view and analyse the recorded data.